# Geometry value into PostgreSQL+PostGIS

Tags: python-3.x, postgis, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3, geopy

I have a problem to insert a `geometry` value into a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database. I'm using `psycopg2` package. I want to store latitude and longitude, that I get using `geopy` library, with the next code:

```
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.geocode(name)
```

I'm very confused about what SQL sentence I have to write. I'm trying

```
sql = """INSERT INTO Sensor(name, value, location, unit, frecuencyUpdate)
                 VALUES(%s, %s, ST_MakePoint(%s, %s),%s, %s)
                 RETURNING id;"""

 cur = conn.cursor()
 cur.execute(sql, (sensor.estacion, sensor.waterState, sensor.getLongitude(), sensor.getLatitude(), sensor.unit, sensor.frecuencyUpdate))
```

And I get the error:

> "doesn't exits relation «sensor»"

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL has a capital S for the table name but it is not quoted, so Postgres is looking for a table with lower case letters. Should you have created the table using the capital letter, you must quote it:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO \"Sensor\"(name, value, location, unit, frecuencyUpdate)
                 VALUES(%s, %s, ST_MakePoint(%s, %s),%s, %s)
                 RETURNING id;"""
```

Comment: Great!!! Thanks a lot!!!! Also frecuencyUpdate need \". You saved my day!